# Django, Subquery, more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: python, django

Here is my model structure

```
class ContentFlag(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        verbose_name="user",
        related_name="object_flags",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    flag = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey("content_type", "object_id")


class Article(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        verbose_name=_("owner"),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        editable=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="owned_pages",
    )
    flags = GenericRelation(ContentFlag, related_query_name="%(class)s_flags")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class User(index.Indexed, AbstractUser):    
    email = EmailField(verbose_name="email", unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(
        blank=True,
        max_length=100,
    )
    flags = GenericRelation(to="core.ContentFlag")
```

I need to calculate User rating based on Flags number. Here is what I do for that

```
    subquery_plus = ContentFlag.objects.filter(
        Q(article_flags__owner_id=OuterRef("id")),
        flag=LIKEDIT_FLAG,
    ).values("id")
    top_users = (
        User.objects.annotate(
            rating_plus=Count(Subquery(subquery_plus)),
        ).order_by("-rating_plus")
    )
```

But I got an error

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to limit your subquery results to 1. You can achieve it by slicing - `[:1]`

```py
top_users = (
    User.objects.annotate(
        rating_plus=Count(Subquery(subquery_plus[:1])),
    ).order_by("-rating_plus")
)
```

Comment: Seems like not working as expected. It just returns 1 for every user